# EntityFramework 6 RC1 Include on Many-to-Many property fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a many-to-many relationship between Agents and AgentGroups (psuedocode, abbreviated).

```
public class Agent { 
    public virtual List<AgentGroup> AgentGroups { get; set; } 
}

public class AgentGroup { 
    public virtual List<Agent> Agents { get; set; } 
}
```

At some point in the code, I want to get all AgentGroups, and I want to prefetch/include the Agents for each group. I *also* want to pre-fill the AgentGroups collection on the Agents. This was working in EF 6 beta, but no longer works in EF 6 rc1:

```
List<AgentGroup> allGroups = context.AgentGroups.Include("Agents").Include("Agents.AgentGroups").ToList();
```

The error message I get is

> Invalid object name 'dbo.AgentAgentGroups'.

And in fact, there isn't a table `AgentAgentGroups`, the table is `dbo.AgentGroupAgents`. Any ideas on getting this to work again?

I currently have no annotations and am not using the fluent API, it's all strictly the default code first conventions.

Comment: Did you create the database before upgrading to rc1? When I try your code I see a table `AgentAgentGroups`, but the beta creates `AgentGroupAgents`. I think you've got a scoop here!

Comment: The initial model didn't have AgentGroups and was created with EF 6 beta. Then I added the AgentGroups concept and created a Migration with EF 6 rc1. The Migration creates the table as AgentGroupAgents!    CreateTable(
                "dbo.AgentGroupAgents", etc

Comment: That's still on my list to delve into one day, the difference between migrations and on-the-fly generation of databases. Looks like the query builder shares code with the latter. I've seen issues before where migration-generated tables didn't seem to match table names in queries. Bad news.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In rc1 there appears to be a change in naming convention of the junction table in many-to-many associations. When I try your model in various EF versions, this is what I see:

- EF5 (stable): `AgentGroupAgents`
- EF6 (beta): `AgentGroupAgents`
- EF6 (rc1): `AgentAgentGroups`

It wouldn't be bad if the beta was different, but rc1 differs from the last RTM version, which makes this a breaking change. Good catch!

**Edit**

[Answer from the EF team](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1677):

> Hello,
>   Prior to EF6 there were some areas of model creation that were non-deterministic - depending on whether you were running on x86 or x64 you could get a different model. The many to many join table name was one of these areas.
>   In EF6 we addressed this to ensure the results would always be the same. Unfortunately, that does mean that for some models (depending on which architecture they were running on) upgrading to EF6 can cause a model change. But the model that is now calculated will be consistent across machines and future versions of EF.
>   If you want to continue using the original name, the best option is to [use the Fluent API to specify the join table name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#ManyToMany).
>   ~Rowan

Comment: I filed an issue at [CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1677).

Comment: I had found other posts indicating the naming convention had changed, so I was aware of that, and I intentionally re-created the Migration. But for whatever reason, it didn't update the table name in the migration. I have since downgraded to the initial migration, deleted the AgentGroups migration, created a new AgentGroups migration, and it's working again.

Comment: OK, that's good. Still, the on-the-fly creation of databases (on the first run of an application) shows these differences, so there is an issue there.