# EntityFramework is naming my mapping table wrong

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following Entity class definition:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class WebUser
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    // more properties...
}
```

Notice that table name is different than the class name. I also have a `ClientUsers` table which is a many-to-many mapping for clients and users. Problem is, when I try to access the `webUser.Clients` property I get the following exception:

```
"Invalid object name 'dbo.ClientWebUsers'."
```

Looks like Entity Framework is trying to guess the name of the third table, but it apparently was not smart enough to take into account the table attribute that I have there. How can I tell EF that it is `ClientUsers` and not `ClientWebUsers`? Also what rule does it follow to know which table name comes first and which one comes second in the new table name? I think it's not alphabetical order.

I'm using EF 5.0. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18909901/861716. Note that the naming convention has changed in EF6, so you better explicitly name the junction table as proposed below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of things you're using Code First, so I'll answer accordingly. If this is incorrect, please let me know.

I believe the convention being used to determine the name of the many-to-many table is determined by the order in which they occur as DbSet properties in your SomeContext : DbContext class.

As for forcing EntityFramework to name your table whatever you like, you can use the Fluent API in the OnModelCreating method of your SomeContext : DbContext class as follows:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("SomeDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<WebUser> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<WebUser>().HasMany(c => c.Clients)
            .WithMany(p => p.WebUsers).Map(
            m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("ClientId");
                m.MapRightKey("UserId");
                m.ToTable("ClientUsers");
            });
    }
}
```

This assumes your classes are something like the following:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class WebUser
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    // more properties...
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<WebUser> WebUsers { get; set; }

    // more properties
}
```

Finally, here's an integration test (NUnit) demonstrating the functionality working. You may need to drop your database before running it as Code First should want to update/migrate/recreate it.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void UseDB()
    {
        var db = new DatabaseContext();

        db.Users.Add(new WebUser { Clients = new List<Client> { new Client() } });
        db.SaveChanges();

        var webUser = db.Users.First();
        var client = webUser.Clients.FirstOrDefault();

        Assert.NotNull(client);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) to relevant documentation for the Fluent API

Answer (score 0):

Rowan's [answer](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2383) (adding here for reference):

Here is the information on how to configure a many-to-many table (including specifying the table name). The code you are after is something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WebUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Clients)
    .WithMany(c => c.WebUsers)
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("ClientUsers");
```

~Rowan